# Tkinter tips - Python - GUI

Tags: python, user-interface, tkinter

I just started a COMP project (Intro course) where we have been learning Python and I'm planning to code a calendar and a task manager. I just started using Tkinter and the GUI didn't look as good I thought it could be. I was wondering if there any tips to improve GUIs that use Tkinter and whether there are other better (and free) alternatives.

Thank you!

Comment: What specific features/elements we're you looking for or hoping would be different?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When possible, use the `ttk` versions of the widgets, being specific as to what is being imported:

```
from tkinter.ttk import LabelFrame
```

*To import the LabelFrame widget, as an example.*

The `ttk` versions of the standard widgets behave similar to their tk cousins, with a few differences.  Certain options are not available, for example `padx/pady/ipadx/ipady` options get reduced to `padding`.  Since you're using 'os native' widgets, certain visual options wouldn't even make sense.

Comment: I recommend against suggesting global imports. PEP8 discourages them.

Comment: @BryanOakley I didn't find the reference on global imports on PEP8. What did you mean? https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/#imports

Comment: @Jako: I used the wrong word when I said "global"; I should have said "wildcard". From PEP8: _"Wildcard imports ( from <module> import * ) should be avoided, as they make it unclear which names are present in the namespace, confusing both readers and many automated tools."_

Comment: @BryanOakley Thanks for the clarification